# Segmentation fault - Linked list implementation

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am getting segmentation fault in my code for implementation of linked list. Any help is appreciated. Thanks. I have purposely added struct methods in here.

```
struct node{
    int data;
    node *next;

    node(int data){
        this->data = data;
        this->next = NULL;
    }

    node(int data, node *next){
        this->data = data;
        this->next = next;
    }
    int getData(){
        return data;
    }
    node* getNextNode(){
        return next;
    }
};

class LinkedList {
    private: 
        node *head,*tail;
    public:
        linked_list(){
            head=NULL;
            tail=NULL;
        }
        void addNode(int data){
            node *temp = new node(data);
            if(head==NULL){
                head = temp;
                tail = temp;
            }
            else {
                tail->next = temp;
                tail = temp;
            }
        }
        void display(){
            node *temp;
            temp = head;
            cout<<"PRINTING LINKED LIST"<<endl; 
            while(temp!=NULL){
                cout<<temp->getData()<<" ";
                temp = temp->getNextNode();
            }
        }

};
```

I get segmentation fault when I invoke the following code :

```
LinkedList myLinkedList;
myLinkedList.addNode(1);
myLinkedList.addNode(2);
myLinkedList.display();
```

Stack overflow is asking for more details, for me to post this question. Putting in some gibberish, please ignore following part : 
Lyrics to 'Humpty Dumpty' by Songs For Children: Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall, Humpty Dumpty had a great fall All the king's horses and all the king's men.

Comment: my impression from SO questions is that if it has no segfault, then it is not a linked list. What is your question? Did you use a debugger?

Comment: btw when SO asks you to put details it was not asking for details on children songs...

Comment: I think the answer to that last bit is "Yes, sir. Yes, sir. Three bags full."

Comment: Actually, you do not have good taste for children songs. Here is a better one :) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mx8s6ZACZFU

Comment: Lol, sorry about that. I couldn't really think of anymore relevant details.

Comment: But thanks for that recommendation @AntoineMorrier , hopefully I won't need it :)

Comment: you could have told us what you already tried to find the error. and you could have put an actual question in your question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here

```
class LinkedList {
    private: 
        node *head,*tail;
    public:
        linked_list() {
            head=NULL;
            tail=NULL;
        }
```

`linked_list` is not the constructor for `LinkedList` because the spelling is different. Obviously it should be like this

```
class LinkedList {
    private: 
        node *head,*tail;
    public:
        LinkedList() {
            head=NULL;
            tail=NULL;
        }
```

Now the code you posted should not have compiled, or at least it should have produced compiler warning messages. Always pay attention to your compiler's warning messages.

Comment: Oh dear! Thanks. incidentally, my compiler didn't throw any warning/error messages. It should have though!

Comment: @DhruvRatanGupta I'm surprised but maybe you need to use some flags to enable the warning messages.

Comment: Is this really a problem? I think compiler should have generated implicit default constructor for `LinkedList` class, which should have initialized both members to `NULL`. If anything, I'd expect compiler error when declaring a function without return type...

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Default constructor will leave pointers uninitialised. But yes I agree I would expect a compiler error but the OP said he didn't even get a warning.